# Replacement of .all() function for Browsers other than IE

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am using following code

```
myEl = document.createElement("myElement") ;
//in a loop
myEl.innerHTML = myEl.innerHTML + currElement.outerHTML ; //some elements getting added to it
var newElement = myEl.all(idToSearch) ;
```

the last line is not working for browsers other than IE..
I am particularly using Chrome, is there any alternative for it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`querySelector()`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljlnafax.php) on elements that aren't yet attached to the document:

```
var newElement = myEl.querySelector("#" + idToSearch);
```

Answer (score 0):

`all` is a proprietary IE extension totally unsupported by standards compliant browsers.

Use `document.getElementById()` or start looking at libraries like jquery (which would also help with the innerHTML problems you're likely to encounter).